# Import data from SQL to Orchard CMS

Tags: sql, import, orchardcms

I have a site based on Orchard CMS with my own ContentType. If I create new object of my ContentType in web interface, I can see it in SQL database. But if I create new row in table of my ContentType (in SQL Management Studio), I can't see new object in web interface. Are there ways to import data from SQL to Orchard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put the data in the right places it should work, but it involves more than one table.  It would be pretty easy to screw up.  The Import/Export feature is probably a more reliable way to go.   If you port your data from SQL to xml first, then import it.  That's probably the way to go.  You can just export a test record first to see what the schema would look like.

Comment: thank you! there are 8 tables in SQL DB which represent my ContentType.